# How to group posts by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to retrieve posts from my database and order them by date posted.

Like this:

11/07/2018

- Post 6
- Post 5

10/07/2018

- Post 4
- Post 3

09/07/2018

- Post 2
- Post 1

I now how to order in :desc or :asc but what i don't know is how to display the date it was created. Let's say 10 posts were created today and three yesterday. I want to display the date above the posts and above the ten for today and three for yesterday.

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: So whats the problem in it. Just sort them by date in descending order.

Comment: Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and make your question a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: I know how to order in desc order but what i don't know is how to display the above the posts. For example if 10 posts are created today. That's what I dont't know.

Comment: Please look into `group_by` ruby method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use group_by, so it will differentiate data with group .
Please use below query

```
Post.
  group_by {
    |post| post.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
  }
```

In response you will get Hash, key is date and value contain records for that date.

Comment: Great.. What if I want to display the date on the grouped post and not individual post?

Comment: you will get all the date in hash , so its up to you how to display it in your view